# How to change default user 'flink' on 'root' in docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, apache-flink

I run flink as docker container from docker-compose file. Here is a part of it:

```
jobmanager:
    image: flink:1.7.2-scala_2.11-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./app-folders/data__unzip
        target: /data_unzip
    expose:
      - "6123"
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    command: jobmanager
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
    networks:
      - dwh-network
```

When i try to add in my compose file

`user : root`

It doesn't work, and when flink starts i see in logs:

`-  OS current user: flink`

So, I see it somehow integrated, mb when it was builded...but is there a way to change it on 'root'?

Comment: https://americanexpress.io/do-not-run-dockerized-applications-as-root/

Comment: Thank you for information. I understand importance of non-root containers, but our server isn't public and not a part of some web app or web site,it's just a standalone etl server with access by ssh only from some ip scopes. There's no need for such security but quick decision is vital.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer - you need to replace docker-entrypoint.sh with your own file by adding volume from your host-machine and correct lines in it from "gosu flink... / su-exec flink..." to "gosu root .../ su-exec root..."